# Why is Chrome extension download size is much lesser than uploaded zip

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I uploaded a zip package for publishing chrome extension in Web Store. The size of zip was 13.7MB after it got published when i downloaded it, it was just 7.0 MB did it got properly. How can i verify ?

Why the size shown in Chrome Store is much less ?

Comment: What was inside the zip file?

Comment: it contains javascript, css, images, nexe and library modules used by nexe for both 32 bit and 64 bit systems.

Comment: Did you by any chance create a `_platform_specific` directory? The CWS is smart enough to exclude platform-specific files that are not relevant to the current platform. See https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#reducing-the-size-of-the-user-download-package.

Comment: Have you compared the files already?

Comment: Thanks Rob W ..Yes I have _platform_specific directory. Looks like based on platform Chrome is removing the non relevant part.

Comment: It's also possible to look where the extension is stored on your computer and see if any files are missing.

Comment: Didn't compared the files as all the tests were passing. So looks all files were present. Was wondering how can google achieve better compression than zip. Finally able to understand that the size was reduced because of _platform_specific directory. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on current platform Chrome removes non relevant part from _platform_specific directory.